# How to access another web, by name in client object model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Iam in site B . There is another site named A .I want to access a list A of site A from site B using client object model.
Can I access it I am using below code.

var context = new SP.ClientContext("/sites/SI");

var web = context.get_web().getByName("Site A");

var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('List A');

where SI is my site collection .Currently I am using this code in site B.  I am not able to fetch data from site A.
Please help

Comment: I would recommend using REST API which you can use within the JSOM development.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? If this is 2013 then REST is a good suggestion, although with 2013 you can use `ClientContext` cross-SPSite anyway, and I can provide an example, but if this is 2010 it might be more difficult

Comment: Basically; 2010: SPServices, 2013: CSOM/REST